# Lock a specific mysql database in shared mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-backup, read-only

I am trying to migrate a database from one cluster to another cluster. In order to avoid any data loss during the migration, I am trying to lock my database with the WRITE operations. But the lock command from mysql doc

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
mysql> SET GLOBAL read_only = ON;
```

will lock the entire database which means this will lock other databases which I don't own and I don't want to lock other databases. Is there a way to lock only specific databases on a shared mysql instances.

Thanks

Comment: Just revoke any user accounts that have write access to the database in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html). You will need to list all tables in the database, but it should do what you expect.